# Google Chart not rendering with AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I have the following code that should render a simple area chart using Google Chart API, but I can't get it to work with an AJAX call (Python backend). The return from the call (stats) is as follows:

```
[
  ['2012-09-17',1000,400],
  ['2012-09-18',1170,460],
  ['2012-09-19',660,1120],
  ['2012-09-20',1030,540]
]
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Uncaught Error: Argument given to addRows must be either a number or an array
```

Is there anything that stands out as being wrong? I have the feeling it is a javascript object issue, but not sure where to proceed from here. Thanks!

Below is the HTML/javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title></title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Quantity');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');

      var options = {
        title: 'Company Performance',
        hAxis: {title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}},
        legend: {position: 'in'},
      };

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/loaddata",
        success: function(stats) {
          var vals = stats;
          data.addRows(vals); 
          var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
          chart.draw(data, options);         
        },
      });  
  }

</script>
</head>

<body>
     <div id="chart_div" style="width: 800px; height: 450px;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: as an aside, this works: `$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/loaddata",
        success: function(stats) {
          data.addRows([
  ['2012-09-17',1000,400],
  ['2012-09-18',1170,460],
  ['2012-09-19',660,1120],
  ['2012-09-20',1030,540]
]); 
          var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
          chart.draw(data, options);         
        },
      });`

Answer (score 1):

I can only advice you to do it the same way as in [this Google's example](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example), by attributing the entire JSON data from your Python script directly to the Javascript variable:

```
var jsonData = $.ajax({
                    url: "/loaddata",
                    dataType:"json",
                    async: false
               }).responseText;
```

Comment: Thanks Stephane! as always, a solution seems to arrive when you have just about given up. A small change seemed to make it work: `data.addRows(eval(vals));` While JSON is probably the best way to do this, I am still a little uncomfortable with the structure :) more to learn..